# How to determine if a particular value is in an array stored in a postgresql field

Tags: arrays, postgresql, search

I have the following postgresql table (named "paperwork"):

```
paperwork_guid  name    primary_attribute   alter_attributes
    123456      test       {1,2,3,4,5}         {9,8,7,6}
    09876       test2      {1,2,3,4}           {9,8,7,6}
```

I would like to return the paperwork_guid for those rows having '5' in the primary_attribute array (In the above table, the result would be '123456').

If there is another question out there on this topic, I have been unable to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
SELECT paperwork_guid
  FROM (SELECT paperwork_guid, unnest(primary_attribute) AS attr
          FROM paperwork) x
  WHERE attr = 5
```

with a `DISTINCT` if an attribute can occur more than once within a `primary_attribute` array.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks, Glenn!

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler one:
`SELECT paperwork_guid FROM paperwork where primary_attribute IN ('5');`